# MongoDB service is terminated after restart linux

Tags: linux, mongodb, systemctl

I've installed mongoDB on linux and created a different instance by running the following:

```
mkdir mongodb
cd mongodb
mkdir data1
mkdir -p data1/db
mkdir -p data1/log

echo "systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: /tmp/mongodb/data1/log/mongod.log
storage:
    dbPath: /tmp/mongodb/data1/db">/tmp/mongodb/data1/db/mongod.cfg
```

im starting the mongoDB by running:

```
/usr/bin/mongod --config /tmp/mongodb/data1/db/mongod.cfg --port 27011 &
```

but once im restart/shut down the machine the service is gone. is it the right approach? how can i use the systemctl for this created instance? what's wrong with the command im running right now?

Comment: Creating a config file as temporary file is very uncommon, I think. Create a (or also server als) permanent file, typically /etc/mongodb.conf. Note, if you like to run several instances at the same time, then you need to specify also different ports.

Comment: How does it matter where I place my config file? i found this https://askubuntu.com/questions/61503/how-to-start-mongodb-server-on-system-start but still no luck

Comment: Because depending on your system setup the files in temp folder are frequently deleted automatically.

Comment: When you run `mkdir mongodb` then folder is created in your current directory. Do you run this from `/tmp`?

Comment: Did you check the logfile?

Comment: As far as I remember you have to copy `xxx.service` file in `/etc/systemd/system` in order to define the `xxx` service. If you like to run several instances, then the files must be different of course.